# Get information from server and print it out in format

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

This interface is happening on a mobile app. I am trying to press a button on my main page (#home)which will change my screen to a sub-page(#benefits) which will display as follows:

Benefit 1

Date: 27 Mar

Days 0

Amount: $100.00

Benefit 2 ....
and so on.

I am trying to use ajax to perform this and the information is obtained from a server url.

For example if I go to www.awebsite.com/getinfo/

I get the following information:

```
[{"amount":"43.00","reference":"benefit 1","due":{"date":"27 Mar","days":0}},
{"amount":"47.00","reference":"benefit 2","due":{"date":"29 Mar","days":1}},
{"amount":"33.00","reference":"benefit 3","due":{"date":"1 Apr","days":5}}]
```

I want to grab these information from the server and print it out as per the format in the beginning.

I am trying to use JSON to format and been trying by going through examples here and the API but unable to do so. I am not sure if my script is right and if I got the format right but the script is not working. If its not too much trouble, can someone show me how exactly I can do this please.

My html main-page:

```
<!--Pressing the Benefits page starts the ajax process plus move me to the subpage benefits-->
<div data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="e">
            <header data-role="header">
                    <h1>Budget Planner</h1>
            </header>
            <article data-role="content">
                <ul data-role="listview" >
                    <li id="benefit_button">
                        <a href="#benefits" data-transition="slidefade">
                            <h1>Benefits</h1>
                            <img src="img/orange-icon.png" alt="benefits">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </article>
</div>
```

My html sub-page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="benefits" data-theme="e">
            <header data-role="header">
            <h1>Benefits</h1>   
        </header>

        <article data-role="content">
            <div data-role="collapsible-set">
                <div data-role="collapsible" id="benefitsList">
                    <!--Hard coded in the information for demo-->
                    <h1>Benefit 1</h1>
                    <p>Date: 27 Mar</p>
                    <p>Days 0</p>
                    <p>Amount: $100.00</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
</div>
```

My Script: (Edited)

```
$("benefit_button").click(function(){
  $.getJSON("http://www.awebsite.com/getinfo/",function(data){
    $.each(data,function(elem){
//Create the h1 and the other elements appending them to    
//benefitsList
$("<h1/>",{
    text:data[elem].reference
}).appendTo("#benefitsList")

$("<p/>",{
    text:"Date: "+ data[elem].due.date
}).appendTo("#benefitsList")

$("<p/>",{
    text:"Days: "+ data[elem].due.days
}).appendTo("#benefitsList")

$("<p/>",{
    text:"Days: "+ data[elem].due.days
}).appendTo("#benefitsList")

$("<p/>",{
    text:"Amount: "+ data[elem].amount
}).appendTo("#benefitsList")

    })
  });
});
```

Comment: See the Fiddle that I added to my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your data you could try something like this to create your elements, just use [**appendTo()**](https://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

You can create the elements on the fly see this [**Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2)

```
var data =[{"amount":"43.00","reference":"benefit 1","due":{"date":"27 Mar","days":0}},
{"amount":"47.00","reference":"benefit 2","due":{"date":"29 Mar","days":1}},
{"amount":"33.00","reference":"benefit 3","due":{"date":"1 Apr","days":5}}];


//Loop for each element on the data
$.each(data,function(elem){
    //Create the h1 and the other elements appending them to    
    //benefitsList
    $("<h1/>",{
        text:data[elem].reference
    }).appendTo("#benefitsList")

    $("<p/>",{
        text:"Date: "+ data[elem].due.date
    }).appendTo("#benefitsList")

    $("<p/>",{
        text:"Days: "+ data[elem].due.days
    }).appendTo("#benefitsList")

    $("<p/>",{
        text:"Days: "+ data[elem].due.days
    }).appendTo("#benefitsList")

    $("<p/>",{
        text:"Amount: "+ data[elem].amount
    }).appendTo("#benefitsList")

})
```

Here is a [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uP8pn/)

Fiddle simulation of JSON response  [**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/uP8pn/2/)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I get the idea on how to append. But how do I store the information into the variable data first? Those information changes day to day. I want to connect to the url each time I go to the subpage to be able to grab the information and store it into the variable data. Can you help to advice how? Thanks so much.

Comment: Data is just a representation of the object of json you're getting using result instead of data should work

Comment: Just to clarify, I have edited my script. Is that what you mean?